# Does Magnus have a claim to the throne of the Kingdom of the Isles?

Tags: raymond-e-feist, riftwar-cycle

In the beginning of *Magician* Pug is adopted into the conDoin family for his rescue of princess Carline. By extension this makes him part of the royal family, somehting that Pug commented on a few times. Which would mean that he has a claim to the throne of the Kingdom of the Isles.

But what about Magnus? At the end of *Shards of a Broken Crown* Prince Patrick is such a jerk to Pug that the latter foregoes his claims and leaves the Kingdom's service. In my eyes this is more or less what Martin did at the end of *Magician*. Yet Martin's descendant Hal keeps saying that he has no claims to the throne because of what his ancestor did, but other people insisted that because no descendant did the same Martin did this doesn't count for Hal, [and we all know how that ended in *Magician's End.*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AwesomeMomentOfCrowning) But wouldn't this mean that Magnus has a similar claim to the throne because he did not give up his claims either? Or do I see this the wrong way? I'm not asking if he would claim it (I figure that he would not) or how big his claim is, only if he has one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, he is in the line of succession.  I don't remember what book it was, but Pug is specifically listed in the order of succession.  As it is hereditary (Pug became in line because of his adoption in the conDion family), Magnus would also be an heir to the throne.

Any descendant of Martin would be excluded, as Martin foreswore the crown for himself and all his descendants.

Comment: in fact, it is not uncommon in the "real world" for sufficiently old royalty to renounce their claim specifically to let their children inherit in their stead unless, as you point out, they purposely remove their entire line from succession.

Comment: That last line is not correct. Hal spents a good deal of the last (two) books saying that he's not in line for the throne, but it is frequently pointed out to him that because Martin is the only one who foreswore the throne Hal still has a claim. The fact that he seems to be popular with many nobles from the West because of his conDoin blood seems to also help.